# Is it possible to use bootstrap-table with Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, bootstrap-table

I am trying to use [BootStrap Table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) with on of my views in an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) App to render a Table.

I tried couple of things as per ["Usage" Documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/) of BootStrap Table, but no luck :(

Has anyone tried it already?

Answer (score 0):

The code for the bootstrap table will want your HTML to already exist in the DOM before it initializes. In the code for your viewmodel add an attached() function. Aurelia will call this during the viewmodel lifecycle after it has been bound to the view and rendered in the DOM. In your attached() function you'll write the code to initialize the table. Use the Via Javascript instructions.

```
export class App {
  message = 'bootstrap-table';

  attached(){
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'Item ID'
    }, {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
    }, {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
    }],
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        price: '$1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        price: '$2'
    }]
    });
  }
}
```

Here is an example that works in Chrome, Edge and Firefox on windows 10: https://plnkr.co/edit/u0Qu5O